# Redefining axes label in pst-plot

Tags: pstricks, labels, pst-plot

I am trying to redefine the labels for x-axis in a [`pst-plot`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-plot) diagram by putting

```
\makeatletter
\def\ps@@@hlabel#1{\small(#1)}
\makeatother
```

in the preamble (see top of page 25 in the [manual](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-plot/doc/pst-plot-doc.pdf)) but then no labels are printed at all.

**Example:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot}

% Label redefinition. (NOT working)
\makeatletter
\def\ps@@@hlabel#1{\small(#1)}
\makeatother

% Makes things easier.
\def\afspil#1#2{%
%  \rput(!2 #1 mul -0.3){\small{(#1)}}  <--  (`manually' plotting of labels)
  \psline[linecolor=red](!2 #1 mul 0)(!2 #1 mul #2)
  \psline[linecolor=red](!2 #1 mul 0.2 sub #2)(!2 #1 mul 0.2 add #2)
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}
  \psaxes[
    labels=none,
    ticks=y,
    ticklinestyle=dotted,
    tickwidth=0.5pt,
    yticksize=0 12.9
  ]{->}(0,0)(-0.3,-0.3)(13.1,8.6)[Sang,0][Afspilninger,90]
  \psaxes[
    dy=1,
    Dy=10,
    labels=y,
    ticks=y,
    ylabelFactor=\cdot 10^3
  ](0,0)(-0.3,-0.3)(13.1,8.6)
  \afspil{1}{6.4098}
  \afspil{2}{5.0320}
  \afspil{3}{7.5437}
  \afspil{4}{6.3253}
  \afspil{5}{0.5735}
  \afspil{6}{6.9024}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

How do I redefine the labels on the x-axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things: first you draw two axes with only `y`-labels, and the macro, which you need to change is `\pst@@@hlabel`. It is correct in the text of page 25, but wrong in the example following the paragraph. The following works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot}

% Label redefinition.
\makeatletter
\def\pst@@@hlabel#1{\small(#1)}
\makeatother

% Makes things easier.
\def\afspil#1#2{%
%  \rput(!2 #1 mul -0.3){\small{(#1)}}  <--  (`manually' plotting of labels)
  \psline[linecolor=red](!2 #1 mul 0)(!2 #1 mul #2)
  \psline[linecolor=red](!2 #1 mul 0.2 sub #2)(!2 #1 mul 0.2 add #2)
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}
  \psaxes[
    labels=none,
    ticks=y,
    ticklinestyle=dotted,
    tickwidth=0.5pt,
    yticksize=0 12.9
  ]{->}(0,0)(-0.3,-0.3)(13.1,8.6)[Sang,0][Afspilninger,90]
  \psaxes[
    dy=1,
    Dy=10,
    ylabelFactor=\cdot 10^3
  ](0,0)(-0.3,-0.3)(13.1,8.6)
  \afspil{1}{6.4098}
  \afspil{2}{5.0320}
  \afspil{3}{7.5437}
  \afspil{4}{6.3253}
  \afspil{5}{0.5735}
  \afspil{6}{6.9024}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to change the size of the label numbers, you can use the keyval `labelFontSize=\scriptstyle`. To use this, you have to load the package `pstricks-add`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot,pstricks-add}
\begin{document}

\psset{xunit=1.3cm,yunit=0.6cm,algebraic=true,dotstyle=*,dotsize=3pt 0,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
\begin{pspicture*}(-1,-4.3)(9,10)
\psgrid[subgriddiv=0,gridcolor=gray,gridwidth=0.4pt,griddots=0,gridlabels=0pt](-1,-4)(9,10)
\psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,xAxis=true,yAxis=true,Dx=1,Dy=1,ticksize=-3pt 0,subticks=2]{->}(0,0)(0,-4)(9,10)
\psplot[plotpoints=200,linecolor=black,algebraic]{0}{9}{(3-3*x)*2.718^(2-x)}
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you show an screen shot of the output of your code in order to *prove* it's an answer? ;-)